# Undefined control sequence during compiling

Tags: compiling

When I am compyling my text in Overleaf I see this message and I have tried to fix it but failed.
Can anyone explain how to correct it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: You are using the control sequence `\h` at line 22 and 27 but it is not defined. Define `\h` or don't use it.

Comment: @wipet, I don't have any \h at lines 22 or 27.

Comment: @wipet, how to define \h?

Comment: You have the text `Finite fields and the (E)rd\h` at line 22. There is `\h` here. I don't know what you mean by `\h` and TeX don't know too. That is the reason why TeX reports error. And that is the reason why I don't tell you how to define `\h` because I don't know your intend of using `\h`.

Comment: @wipet, that is really weird but there is no such text in my file.

Comment: Look in your bibliography file.  "Line 22" is possibly in a supplementary file that TeX creates as part of its compilation.

Comment: @Teepeemm, ohh I see the line 22 in my bibliography file.  "TITLE = {Erd\H{o}s distance problem in vector spaces over finite fields}," How to fix that?

Comment: You have `{E}rd\h{o}s` but it may be `{E}rd\H{o}s` or better `Erdős`.

Comment: The error says you're using a lower case `h`.

Comment: @wipet, Thanks a lot! I fixed! +1

Answer (score 1):

The lowercase `\h` was probably caused by the application of "sentence case" to the title of the bib item. Wrapping braces around just the `{E}` isn't sufficient in this case; wrap the whole name in braces: `{Erd\H{o}s}` (or enter it directly, as suggested elsewhere.

This change must be made in the `.bib` file to persist.

As pointed out by @egreg in a comment, in the author field, `Erd{\H{o}}s` would be a more correct form.

Comment: The correct input for BibTeX should be `Erd{\H{o}}s` when in the `author` field, but of course `{Erd\H{o}s}` is good in the `title` field.

Comment: Good point.  (I'm more used to bibliographies that don't modify the casing of author names.)